# Water drops on a moving spider web

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

I'm trying to create a spider web that is dynamically moving using wind and vortex force fields. Water drops, in slightly random sizes, should be sliding down the threads at a random but constant speed. I've tried a few different scenarios but all without success. Here's what I tried already.

I created a cylinder, made it very thin and long and added a cloth modifier with pins at the top and bottom. Then I added a path and gave it a shrinkwrap modifier to follow the cylinder. Next I added a particle system and added a curve guide force field on the path so the particles would follow the curve. Lastly I added the vortex and wind force fields. Unfortunately this setup doesn't work. The particles keep following the initial shape of the path rather than the dynamically calculated shrinkwrapped curve.

The thread has the perfect movement so I'm nearly there. Now what I need is to be able to get the drops stick to the thread (e.g. cylinder) while sliding down at random speeds.

I could solve this with shape keys on detached meshes in the cylinder object, but I would rather like to have the drops generated by a particle system. Eventually I will need to have about 50 threads, every one with it's own random set of drops, so manually generating all of them would be a massive job :)

Comment: I found this video helpful for understanding curve guides: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPdHEVdanJY   Maybe you'll find a clue in there.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's a comprehensive explanation of the curve guide but  it doesn't contain the info I need. In my scenario I think the influence of the shrinkwrap modifier on the path is only visual and doesn't actually change the geometry of the curve. Ss While I can see the path change, the curve force field only uses the original geometry to guide the particles.